# Refer to the last column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do some manipulation on the last column in a generic way.

I found here on the forums this nice piece of code that returns the name of the last columns:

```
tail(names(train),1) #returns [1] "last"
```

I still can't figure out how to reference directly to my dataset's last columns as:

`data$last`

Answer (score 87, accepted):

just use `ncol()` to get the index of the last col

```
data[,ncol(data)]
```

Comment: This appears to not work for data tables, only data frames. Am I missing something, why would this be? I'm running R 3.6.2 and data table 1.12.8.

Comment: @jeromeResearch for data.table, use `x[, ncol(x), with = FALSE]` or use ".."  `ix <- ncol(x); x[, ..ix ]`.

Answer (score 15):

Take the first element of the `rev`ersed vector of column names:

```
rev(names(mtcars))[1]
[1] "carb"
```

Similarly, to get the last column, you can use

```
rev(mtcars)[1]
```

Comment: Besides being a clever solution, you answer solved another problem that I had. +1

Comment: This creates a dataframe when using the extracted vector (from a dataframe) in a mathematical operation. Not ideal.

Answer (score 6):

To refer to last column:

```
colnames(data)[ncol(data)]
```

Answer (score 6):

I prefer @Troy's solution, here is another way:

```
train[, tail(colnames(train), 1)]
```

Comment: If you know the last name,   then  `train[,'last']` works; zx's solution is more flexible.

Answer (score 5):

[Troy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21781631/4575331) is simpler, and can be adapted to refer to "n" elements before the last column, using the ":" operator.

If you want to refer to the last threee columns, you could write:

```
data[,ncol(data)] # refers to the last column
data[,(ncol(data)-2):ncol(data)] # refers to the three last columns
```

Answer (score 4):

Function `last_col()` from `tidyselect` package may help. See also answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44353413

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tail`, but you have to coerce to list:

```
tail(as.list(mtcars), 1)
```

This will return a vector with the contents of the column.  If you want to preserve the structure, you can use:

```
utils:::tail.default(mtcars, 1)
```

so that `tail` treats the input like a list.  The only reason really to use this approach over Troy's are if you want more than just the last column (i.e. last N), where it becomes a lot easier to do it this way.

Comment: ah yea that `list(data.frame)` to get the column names.. well i'm not using `R` for general purpose programming so just memorize these "interesting" things

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of indexing just the last column name. Reference the
`names(df1[,ncol(df1)])`:

```r
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  add_column(new1 = NA, new2 = NA, new3 = NA, .after = names(df1[,ncol(df1)]))
```