# R move column to last using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

For a data.frame with **n** columns, I would like to be able to move a column from any of **1-(n-1)** positions, to be the nth column (i.e. a non-last column to be the last column). I would also like to do it using `dplyr`. I would like to do so without simply typing out the names of all the columns.

For example:

```
data<-data.frame(a=1:5, b=6:10, c=11:15)
```

This works, but isn't the `dplyr` way:

```
data[,c(colnames(data)[colnames(data)!='b'],'b')]
```

This is the `dplyr` way to make column `b` first:

```
data%>%select(b, everything())
```

But this doesn't work to make column `b` last:

```
data%>%select(everything(), b)
```

This works, but requires me to type out all the columns:

```
data%>%select(a,c,b)
```

So is there an elegant dplyr way to do this?

Related questions:

- [move column to first in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286419/move-column-to-first-in-a-data-frame)
- [How does one reorder columns in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620885/how-does-one-reorder-columns-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 164, accepted):

After some tinkering, the following works and requires very little typing.

`data %>% select(-b,b)`

**UPDATE: dplyr 1.0.0**

`dplyr 1.0.0` introduces the `relocate` verb:

`data %>% relocate(b, .after = last_col())`

I still prefer the old "hacky" way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this easy and simple way.

Appreciated Dule.

Comment: Dule, you could change the accepted answer to either this or Arthur Yip's, as they're decidedly cleaner and more 'elegant' than Arkun's (although it works fine.)

Comment: The other answers teach me more about dplyr, but this answer is the shortest of them all! So I'd consider it a toss-up.

Answer (score 84):

**Update:**

`dplyr::relocate`, a new verb introduced in dplyr 1.0.0, is now my preferred solution, since it is explicit about what you are doing, you can continue to pick variables using `tidyselect` helpers, and you can specify exactly where to put the columns with `.before` or `.after`

`data %>% relocate(b, .after = last_col())`
(same as dule arnaux's update)

**Original answer**

```
data%>%select(-b,everything())
```

will move variable b to the end.

This is because a negative variable in the first position of select elicits a special behavior from select(), which is to insert all the variables. Then it removes b, and then it gets added back with the everything() part.

Explained by Hadley himself: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2838

Also see this other answer for other examples of how to move some columns to the end and other columns to the beginning:
[How does dplyr's select helper function everything() differ from copying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171891/how-does-dplyrs-select-helper-function-everything-differ-from-copying)

Comment: This is cleaner than the answer from dule arnaux if you are moving several columns to the back.

Comment: Note that this answer does not respect the order of variables, in case you pass multiple names, like `-c(a,b,c)` instead of just `-b`. With this solution, the order of variables will reflect the order in which they were already in the data frame. So if the column order was `a, c, b, d, e, f`, this answer will return `d, e, f, a, c, b`. Dule arnaux's answer will return `d, e, f, a, b, c`

Answer (score 14):

We can either use

```
data %>%
    select(-one_of('b'), one_of('b'))
#  a  c  b
#1 1 11  6
#2 2 12  7
#3 3 13  8
#4 4 14  9
#5 5 15 10
```

Or

```
data %>%
    select(matches("[^b]"), matches("b"))
```

or with the `select_`

```
data %>% 
    select_(.dots = c(setdiff(names(.), 'b'), 'b'))
#  a  c  b
#1 1 11  6
#2 2 12  7
#3 3 13  8
#4 4 14  9
#5 5 15 10
```

Comment: Great answer always, What does one_of do? , does it actually picks the name in quotes, unlike other options ? Thanks

Comment: @Bankelal Thanks. You can have a vector of string names in `one_of` to match and pick it up

Comment: +1 for using `one_of` as protection for missing columns. Combine with Arthur Yip's answer for `data %>% select(-one_of('b'), everything())`, which puts the removed column back at the end with the everything() call.

Comment: I think `matches("[^b]"), matches("b")` is very clever and could be really useful in other situations.

Answer (score 5):

Since there's no ready-made solution to this in dplyr you could define your own little function to do it for you:

```
move_last <- function(DF, last_col) {
    match(c(setdiff(names(DF), last_col), last_col), names(DF))
}
```

You can then use it easily in a normal `select` call:

```
mtcars %>% select(move_last(., "mpg")) %>% head()
```

You can also move multiple columns to the end:

```
mtcars %>% select(move_last(., c("mpg", "cyl"))) %>% head()
```

And you can still supply other arguments to select, for example to remove a  column:

```
mtcars %>% select(move_last(., "mpg"), -carb) %>% head()
```

Comment: Why do you say there is no ready made solution in dplyr? Akrun's solution example apears to be one.

Comment: True, dplyr does allow for this, but Hadley notes that moving/reordering variables is "not usually that important, so you'll need to muddy along with select() for now." https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2838

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- df[, c(which(colnames(df) != "YourColumnName"), which(colnames(df) == "YourColumnName"))]
```

Comment: The last two words in the question are: using dplyr. This answer does not use dplyr.